# UrlEncodedSlash blocked by HttpFirewall (Grails 3.3.0.RC1; Spring-security-core 3.2.0.M1)

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails3

I find this errors in my logs:

```
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The requestURI cannot contain encoded slash. Got /;lm=1488887514;m=js;asset=delayedElements%2Fsnippet;tf;ucm=353df4434086482d9d1d7b89758e156e/
        at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.DefaultHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(DefaultHttpFirewall.java:56)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:193)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
...
```

And I found this solution which probably works in Spring Boot.
[Spring security DefaultHttpFirewall - The requestURI cannot contain encoded slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588506/spring-security-defaulthttpfirewall-the-requesturi-cannot-contain-encoded-slas)

Can I, and how, apply this in Grails?
Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT 1:

This is how I implemented the suggestion by Sudhir:

Here I created the new class:

[image: Here I created the new class:]

This is how the implementation looks like:

```
package fnx.security;

import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.DefaultHttpFirewall;

public class CustomHttpFirewall extends DefaultHttpFirewall {
    CustomHttpFirewall() {
        boolean allowUrlEncodedSlash = true;
    }
}
```

And this is how it is included in application.yml:

```
 grails:
     plugin:
        springsecurity:
            httpFirewallBeanClass: 'fnx.security.CustomHttpFirewall'
```

Anything missing or wrong?

Comment: Did u try debugging it in debugger to make sure ur custom firewall is used and allowUrlEncodedSlash is true ?

Comment: I tried, but I don't know where to set the breakpoint and where to see if the CustomHttpFirewall is used.

Comment: If I set a breakpoint in CustomHttpFirewall class, it at least doesn't stop there.

Comment: That mean your custom class is not being used. put break point in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin's doWithSpring -- https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy#L919

Comment: I was finally able to make the class called. The breakpoint now triggers every time I deploy the war file (or run the project) during the spring security configuration. However, the error log still shows the same errors...

Comment: Oh, i am out of suggestions now, i have to try to reproduce the issue locally and thn investigate the fix

Comment: wait, @kloker dont do boolean allowUrlEncodedSlash = true; but just = allowUrlEncodedSlash = true; remove the boolean, you dont want to define a local variable, u want to set the variable value which is defined in parent class.. see my example doesnt have the local variable declared

Comment: I had it first without the "boolean" but the project then fails to compile...

Comment: What error do u get ? -- it should compile just fine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default spring security core plugin uses `DefaultHttpFirewall` you can create a subclass by extending `DefaultHttpFirewall` and set the property `allowUrlEncodedSlash` to true from constructor.

```
 CustomHttpFirewall extends DefaultHttpFirewall {
   CustomHttpFirewall() {
     allowUrlEncodedSlash = true
   }
}
```

And then configure spring security to use your custom firewall class as below.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.httpFirewallBeanClass = "full name of your class"
```

Note tested, but this should work.

Comment: Sounds reasonable and I was able to implement it. I will award the bounty as soon as I was able to prove the solution in the productive environment, as the error only occurs there. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hi Sudhir, I edited the question with a description of how I implemented your suggestion. Is there something missing?

Comment: Hi Sundhir, though I was not able to test your last comment in productive environment, I awarded you the bounty. If I can validate that the solution works, I will also accept the answer later. Anyway, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: No worries, comment if you still cant get it to work